# Laravel - How to display employee fullname using dropdownlist on change

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel project I want to load employee fullname based on dropdown change of the selected employee.

Controller:

```
public function findEmployee(Request $request){
 $data =  HrEmployee::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(employee_code, " - ", first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name'))->where('id', $request->id)->first();

 return response()->json($data);
}
```

route/web.php

```
Route::any('get/findEmployee','LeavesController@findEmployee')->name('get.employee.all');
```

view

```
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group" method = "get">
            <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employees tabindex="1" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="select">Select Employees</option>
            @foreach($managerfilters as $managerfilter)
                <option value="{{ $managerfilter->id }}" {{ request()->input('employee_id') == $managerfilter->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $managerfilter->employee_code }} - {{ $managerfilter->first_name }} {{ $managerfilter->last_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
             </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#employee_id', function() {
        var air_id =  $(this).val();

        var a = $(this).parent();
        var op = "";

   $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ route('get.employee.all') }}',
            data: { 'id': air_id ,'_token':'{{ csrf_token()}}'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                 $('#employee_name').html(data.fullname);
                 },
            error:function(){
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On dropdownlist change, I expected to see the full_name of the selected employee on

```
           <span class="font-weight-bold">
                For: <span id="employee_name"></span>
            </span>
```

When I click on the select dropdown, on change I expected it to displays the result of:

```
For: <span id="employee_name"></span>
```

However, when I click on the select dropdown, on change it displays the result of:

```
For: <span id="employee_name"></span>
```

But as soon as the page finish loading, it clears off

```
<span id="employee_name"></span>.
```

Why? How do I resolve that?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. You are using JS to change content of the page then reload page for some reason?

Comment: @nikistag - What do I do?